# Setting ComboBox Selected Value to AD Query

Tags: vb.net, combobox, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm running an AD query to pull selected attributes from a users profile. I'm selecting extensionAttribute3, 4, 5, 6, 7 & 8. Although I can get the result to display as text, I'd like to set the selected vlaue of a combobox to the results.

So extension attribute 3, 5 & 7 = security questions, 4, 6 & 8 are the answers. I have 3 comboboxes, each with a list of 15 possible security questions users can select from, and then provide answers to. I've got my script to update AD with the questions & answers selected. However when I run the application again, I'd like to pull the existing questions from extensionAttribute 3, 5 & 7, as set as the default selected foreach combobox.

Current AD Query Code:

```
Private Function GetUserProperties()
    Dim ADName As String = GetLogonName()
    Dim CurrentPIN As String = Nothing
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
    Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
    Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    Dim Q1Value As String = Nothing
    dirSearcher.Filter = ("(samAccountName=" & ADName & ")")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute3")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute4")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute5")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute6")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute7")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute8")
    dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    Try
        Dim dirResult As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
        bSuccess = Not (dirResult Is Nothing)
        If dirResult Is Nothing OrElse dirResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("extensionAttribute3").Value Is Nothing Then
            Return "<not set>"
        Else
            Q1Value = dirResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("extensionAttribute3").Value.ToString
            Q1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = Q1Value
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        bSuccess = False
        MsgBox("No Connection to the domain." & Environment.NewLine & "Please connect to corporate network & try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Network Error")
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear.
I'm having problems retuning the values of extensionAttribute 3 to 8 separatly, and in a combobox or textbox. I only ever get the first result returned. Ic an't seem to get multiple values returned from the function.

Comment: Currently when run extensionAttribute3 is returned. But I cant get extensionAttribute4-8 to also display.

I call the fucntion as below:
`Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Try
Dim ADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
ADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
Dim DisplayName As String = ADUser.GivenName & " " & ADUser.Surname
Username.Text = DisplayName
extension3.Text = GetUserProperties()
ComboBox1.SelectedText = GetUserProperties()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Error")
End Try
End Sub`

Comment: You mean just repeating the if-else block inside the try-catch for  extensionAttribute4-8 does not work?

Comment: One more thing, you already put extensionAttribute3-8 to properties to load. Why not get them directly from SearchResult instead of bind to DirectoryEntry? (e.g. dirResult.Properties("extensionAttribute3"))

Comment: You mean something like
`Dim Q1 As String
Dim A1 As String
Dim dirResult As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
Q1 = dirResult.Properties["extensionAttribute4"][0]
A1 = dirResult.Properties["extensionAttribute5"][0]`
When I try this I get an error:
_Value of type 'System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'._

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to format code in comments, i put them here instead.
I'm not VB programmer, may have syntax error.

You don't provide code for extensionAttribute4-8, so it's hard to find what's wrong with them. Do you mean for extensionAttribute4-8, just repeating the if-else block inside the try-catch does not work?
For example, you cannot get value of extensionAttribute4 below?

```
' code for extensionAttribute3, omitted here
....

' code for extensionAttribute4
If dirResult Is Nothing OrElse dirResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("extensionAttribute4").Value Is Nothing Then
    Return "<not set>"
Else
    A1Value = dirResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("extensionAttribute4").Value.ToString
    A1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = A1Value
End If

' repeat for extensionAttribute5-8
....
```

For using the attribute already loaded in SearchResult, you already handle the conversion to string problem (mentioned in comment) by calling ToString. You can just do the same thing. But instead of checking `dirResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("...").Value Is Nothing`, you should check `dirResult.Properties("...").Count > 0`.

```
    Dim dirResult As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
    bSuccess = Not (dirResult Is Nothing)
    If dirResult Is Nothing OrElse dirResult.Properties("extensionAttribute3").Count <= 0 Then
        Return "<not set>"
    Else
        Q1Value = dirResult.Properties("extensionAttribute3")[0].ToString
        Q1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = Q1Value
    End If
```